# Is there a default sort flag for gridjs?

Tags: gridjs

I'm trying to find out if there's a default sort column setting for GridJS.
https://gridjs.io/docs/examples/sorting

Looking at this - and *trying* to understand the code - I don't see anything obvious.

Does anybody know if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is. If your data is dynamic however, you could just sort the data yourself before populating the table.